# Why isn't my locally pip-installed package importable?

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to create and install a Python package, but no matter what I try, I cannot get it to be importable. I've followed the tutorial on the official website and in both of my books and on three different websites to the letter and cannot get it going, nor to produce an error I can understand or find helpful Google/SO results for. I'd appreciate any explanation of what I'm doing wrong.

## Folder structure

```
src/
    __init__.py
    stuff.py
pyproject.toml
```

### `__init__.py`

```
from stuff import *
```

### `stuff.py`

```
def dance() -> int:
    return 20
```

### `pyproject.toml`

```
[project]
name = "applesauce"
version = "0.0.1"
authors = [
{ name="Jane Doe", email="janedoe@example.com" },
]
description = "A test package"
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.7"
classifiers = [
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent",
]

[project.urls]
"Homepage" = "https://example.com/applesauce"
"Bug Tracker" = "https://example.com/applesauce/issues"
```

## What I try

```
$ python -m pip install ~/applesauce

Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Installing backend dependencies ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: applesauce
Building wheel for applesauce (pyproject.toml) ... done
Created wheel for applesauce: filename=applesauce-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl size=1539 sha256=7aad1073d884974ff119dc4ac04b40a2daaecf6b3b45f34b3de5bfd55cfa4c67
Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-an0mxg3o/wheels/a2/5b/ce/6e4327bbc99ccd453f25abb9e6258bd6d475ba061d0377c48f
Successfully built applesauce
Installing collected packages: applesauce
Successfully installed applesauce-0.0.1

$ python -c "import applesauce"

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'applesauce'
```

This also does not work if I `python -m build` and then install the .whl file, if I use setuptools, if I try on Windows, if I install as editable, if I use absolute paths, if I use relative paths, if I use `--no-index`... I'm completely out of ideas.

Comment: I would check what version of python is being called via 'python -m' and compare that to 'pip install'; If pip is installing to python2 and 'python -m' is using python3 that would be the underlying issue. Are you using venv?

Comment: when I install your code and check files in folder with modules then I see it doesn't create folder `applesauce` but it copy `stuff.py` directly to folder with modules and I can run `python -c 'import stuff'` . I never created module but maybe you should keep code in `src/applesauce`

Comment: when I moved code from `src` to `src/applesauce` then it installs it correctly and I can run `python -c 'import applesauce'`

Comment: BTW: documentation [Packaging Python Projects — Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) also shows code in `src/example_package_YOUR_USERNAME_HERE/`, not in `src/`

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep code in `src/applesauce`

```
src/
    applesauce/
        __init__.py
        stuff.py
pyproject.toml
```

Even documentation [Packaging Python Projects — Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) shows code in `src/example_package_YOUR_USERNAME_HERE/`, not in `src/`

---

**EDIT:**

As @wim noticed in comment you have to use `.` in `import` to have relative `import`

```
from .stuff import *
```

Comment: The import statement in `__init__.py` also needs to change. Not `from stuff import *` but `from .stuff import *`.